# How to filter two dimensional array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am trying to build an weather forecast application using Open Weather API and in my forecast class I have following struct type.

```
struct ForecastWeather {
    public private(set) var date: String    
    public private(set) var weatherDetails: [WeatherInfo]
}

struct WeatherInfo {
    public private(set) var weatherImage: String
    public private(set) var time: String
    public private(set) var weatherType: String
    public private(set) var temperature: String
}
```

I need to use two dimensional array because in my table view there are sections for forecast datas. I am putting objects into `var forecastWeathers = [ForecastWeather]()` array.

```
ForecastWeather(date: "Thursday", weatherDetails: [WeatherForecast.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "01d", time: "12:00", weatherType: "Clear", temperature: "35.0")])
ForecastWeather(date: "Thursday", weatherDetails: [WeatherForecast.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "02d", time: "15:00", weatherType: "Clouds", temperature: "31.0")])
ForecastWeather(date: "Thursday", weatherDetails: [WeatherForecast.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "01n", time: "18:00", weatherType: "Clear", temperature: "21.0")])
ForecastWeather(date: "Friday", weatherDetails: [WeatherForecast.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "03n", time: "21:00", weatherType: "Clouds", temperature: "16.0")])
ForecastWeather(date: "Friday", weatherDetails: [WeatherForecast.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "10n", time: "00:00", weatherType: "Rain", temperature: "13.0")])
ForecastWeather(date: "Friday", weatherDetails: [WeatherForecast.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "10d", time: "03:00", weatherType: "Rain", temperature: "14.0")])
ForecastWeather(date: "Monday", weatherDetails: [WeatherForecast.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "10d", time: "12:00", weatherType: "Rain", temperature: "19.0")])
ForecastWeather(date: "Monday", weatherDetails: [WeatherForecast.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "10d", time: "15:00", weatherType: "Rain", temperature: "19.0")])
ForecastWeather(date: "Monday", weatherDetails: [WeatherForecast.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "03n", time: "18:00", weatherType: "Clouds", temperature: "16.0")])
```

In my table view and I need to give that sections into it like `WeatherService.instance.forecastWeathers[indexPath.section].weatherDetails[indexPath.row]`. It is now giving me an error because I have 3 same Thursday object inside it. How can I map or filter `forecastWeathers` array which contains date information only once because I have multiple sections I have tried to use map function but I could not be successful.

Edit here is my API call

```
        let json = JSON(value)

        for i in 0..<json["list"].count {
            let icon = json["list"][i]["weather"][0]["icon"].stringValue    // Image icon
            let  date = self.convertUnixDate(fromDoubleTo: json["list"][i]["dt"].doubleValue)
            let weatherType = json["list"][i]["weather"][0]["main"].stringValue.capitalized
            let temperature = "\(self.temperatureConverter(kelvinTo: json["list"][i]["main"]["temp"].doubleValue))"
            let time = self.convertTime(timeArr: json["list"][i]["dt_txt"].stringValue)

            let forecastObj = ForecastWeather(date: date, weatherDetails: [WeatherInfo(weatherImage: icon, time: time, weatherType: weatherType, temperature: temperature)])
            print(forecastObj)
            self.forecastWeathers.append(forecastObj)
        }
```

Also there is API result [5 day forecast](http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22)

Here is my table view delegate methods

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return WeatherService.instance.newForecastWeathers.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return WeatherService.instance.newForecastWeathers[section].date.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = forecastTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId) as? ForecastCell else { return ForecastCell() }   
    cell.configureCell(weatherDetails: WeatherService.instance.newForecastWeathers[indexPath.section].weatherDetails[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .orange
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = WeatherService.instance.newForecastWeathers[section].date
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 45, y: 5, width: 100, height: 35)
    view.addSubview(label)
    return view
}
```

Comment: look at my answer

Comment: i've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not using the inner `weatherDetails` as an array, since you always only add just one element.
So, you'll have to add `WeatherInfo`s belonging to the same day to that array, maybe in this way:

```
struct ForecastWeather {
    public private(set) var date: String    
    public private(set) var weatherDetails = [WeatherInfo]()
    public init (date:String) {
      self.date = date
    }
    public mutating func addInfo(_ info:WeatherInfo) {
        weatherDetails.append(info)
    }
}

struct WeatherInfo {
    public private(set) var weatherImage: String
    public private(set) var time: String
    public private(set) var weatherType: String
    public private(set) var temperature: String
}

var thursday = ForecastWeather(date: "Thursday")
thursday.addInfo(WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "01d", time: "12:00", weatherType: "Clear", temperature: "35.0"))
thursday.addInfo(WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "02d", time: "15:00", weatherType: "Clouds", temperature: "31.0"))

var friday = ForecastWeather(date: "Friday")
friday.addInfo(WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "03n", time: "21:00", weatherType: "Clouds", temperature: "16.0"))
// ...

let forecastWeathers = [thursday, friday /* ... */]
```

Comment: I think he wants to use functional programming with already created array

Comment: Thanks for the answer but for the weather forecast I do not know what will be the next 5 days so I could not add an object like thursday, friday. There is some time stamp in API and ı am converting it into day names.

Comment: @Vyacheslav I'm not sure about this. I think it depends somehow on how the data is being acquired. The usage of the inner array is not correct in any way.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen you really don't know the full application logic to be sure:)

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Actually I am little bit confused what is the wrong part about my logic?

Comment: @AtalayAsa The thing is that your member `weatherDetails` is an array of `WeatherInfo`, but you don't use it as an array, because you only ever store one single `WeatherInfo` instance into that array. So either you'll have to store multiple instances into that array, all belonging to the same day, or not have an array at all. I think you want the first, not the latter. I also think you should use a dictionary, as Vyacheslav posted.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed some errors and allow `weatherDetails` to be public to simplify appending. This is a functional-style. With sorting.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

struct ForecastWeather {
    public private(set) var date: String
    public var weatherDetails: [WeatherInfo]

    public var index: Int {
        return ForecastWeather.weekdays[date] ?? 0
    }

    private static let weekdays: [String: Int] = ["Sunday": 0, "Monday": 1, "Thuesday": 2, "Wednesday": 3, "Thursday": 4, "Friday": 5, "Saturday": 6]
}

struct WeatherInfo {
    public private(set) var weatherImage: String
    public private(set) var time: String
    public private(set) var weatherType: String
    public private(set) var temperature: String
}

var forecastWeathers = [ForecastWeather]()
forecastWeathers.append(ForecastWeather(date: "Thursday", weatherDetails: [WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "01d", time: "12:00", weatherType: "Clear", temperature: "35.0")]))
forecastWeathers.append(ForecastWeather(date: "Thursday", weatherDetails: [WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "02d", time: "15:00", weatherType: "Clouds", temperature: "31.0")]))
forecastWeathers.append(ForecastWeather(date: "Thursday", weatherDetails: [WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "01n", time: "18:00", weatherType: "Clear", temperature: "21.0")]))
forecastWeathers.append(ForecastWeather(date: "Friday", weatherDetails: [WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "03n", time: "21:00", weatherType: "Clouds", temperature: "16.0")]))
forecastWeathers.append(ForecastWeather(date: "Friday", weatherDetails: [WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "10n", time: "00:00", weatherType: "Rain", temperature: "13.0")]))
forecastWeathers.append(ForecastWeather(date: "Friday", weatherDetails: [WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "10d", time: "03:00", weatherType: "Rain", temperature: "14.0")]))
forecastWeathers.append(ForecastWeather(date: "Monday", weatherDetails: [WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "10d", time: "12:00", weatherType: "Rain", temperature: "19.0")]))
forecastWeathers.append(ForecastWeather(date: "Monday", weatherDetails: [WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "10d", time: "15:00", weatherType: "Rain", temperature: "19.0")]))
forecastWeathers.append(ForecastWeather(date: "Monday", weatherDetails: [WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "03n", time: "18:00", weatherType: "Clouds", temperature: "16.0")]))

var storedForecastWeatherIndicies: [String: ForecastWeather] = [:]

forecastWeathers.forEach { value in
    guard storedForecastWeatherIndicies[value.date] == nil else {
        // if is already found
        storedForecastWeatherIndicies[value.date]?
            .weatherDetails
            .append(contentsOf: value.weatherDetails)
        return
    }
    // if a new value for the Dictinary
    storedForecastWeatherIndicies[value.date] = value
}

let result = storedForecastWeatherIndicies.values.map { $0 }.sorted { first, second in first.index < second.index }

print(result)
```

> [__lldb_expr_7.ForecastWeather(date: "Monday", weatherDetails:
>   [__lldb_expr_7.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "10d", time: "12:00",
>   weatherType: "Rain", temperature: "19.0"),
>   __lldb_expr_7.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "10d", time: "15:00", weatherType: "Rain", temperature: "19.0"),
>   __lldb_expr_7.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "03n", time: "18:00", weatherType: "Clouds", temperature: "16.0")]),
>   __lldb_expr_7.ForecastWeather(date: "Thursday", weatherDetails: [__lldb_expr_7.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "01d", time: "12:00",
>   weatherType: "Clear", temperature: "35.0"),
>   __lldb_expr_7.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "02d", time: "15:00", weatherType: "Clouds", temperature: "31.0"),
>   __lldb_expr_7.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "01n", time: "18:00", weatherType: "Clear", temperature: "21.0")]),
>   __lldb_expr_7.ForecastWeather(date: "Friday", weatherDetails: [__lldb_expr_7.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "03n", time: "21:00",
>   weatherType: "Clouds", temperature: "16.0"),
>   __lldb_expr_7.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "10n", time: "00:00", weatherType: "Rain", temperature: "13.0"),
>   __lldb_expr_7.WeatherInfo(weatherImage: "10d", time: "03:00", weatherType: "Rain", temperature: "14.0")])]

**EDIT**

This is incorrect: `date.count` is lenght of your string. not the array

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return WeatherService.instance.newForecastWeathers[section].date.count
}
```

use `weatherDetails` instead

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return WeatherService.instance.newForecastWeathers[section].weatherDetails.count
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information however when I use in my table view it gives me an error index out of range `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = forecastTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId) as? ForecastCell else { return ForecastCell() }
        
        cell.configureCell(weatherDetails: WeatherService.instance.newForecastWeathers[indexPath.section].weatherDetails[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }` btw newForecastWeathers is an array that you created as a result.

Comment: @AtalayAsa post your full table view delegates

Comment: I thinks the problem is about 'number of sections' and 'number of rows in section'